# SQL fails when a constant string field is added

Tags: sql, string, field

When I add a constant string as a field, I get an error message

Here is the error message:

I would like to add the table name as a column for my rows in an SQL view, I am getting an error message:

Executed SQL statement:

[...]

Error Source: .Net SQL client data provider

Error Message: all queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions and their target lists.

```
SELECT        Location, ClientID, Type_C, Todays_Date, '1100_vAC' as S_Table

FROM            dbo.1100_vAC

UNION ALL

SELECT        Location, ClientID, Type_C, Todays_Date, Time_Stamp, '1100_vAD' as S_Table
FROM            dbo.1100_vAD
UNION ALL
SELECT        Location, ClientID, Type_C, Todays_Date, Time_Stamp,  '1101_AC' as S_Table
FROM            dbo.1101_AC
UNION ALL
SELECT        Location, ClientID, Type_C, Todays_Date, Time_Stamp, '1101_AA' as S_Table
FROM            dbo.1101_AA
UNION ALL
SELECT        Location, ClientID, Type_C, Todays_Date, Time_Stamp, '1102_AC' as S_Table
FROM            dbo.1102_AC;
```

I would like to see for each row the source table.

Comment: `Time_Stamp, Time_Stamp,` - You have a column twice?

Comment: Only once, that's a mistake...

Comment: Which part of the error message is not clear to you???  You don't have the same number of columns in your `SELECT`s.

Answer (score 0):

You should correct your code (remove the duplicate time_stamp)

```
SELECT        Location, ClientID, Type_C, Todays_Date, Time_Stamp, '1100_vAC' as S_Table

FROM            dbo.1100_vAC

UNION ALL

SELECT        Location, ClientID, Type_C, Todays_Date, Time_Stamp,  '1100_vAD' as S_Table
FROM            dbo.1100_vAD
UNION ALL
SELECT        Location, ClientID, Type_C, Todays_Date, Time_Stamp,  '1101_AC' as S_Table
FROM            dbo.1101_AC
UNION ALL
SELECT        Location, ClientID, Type_C, Todays_Date, Time_Stamp,  '1101_AA' as S_Table
FROM            dbo.1101_AA
UNION ALL
SELECT        Location, ClientID, Type_C, Todays_Date, Time_Stamp,  '1102_AC' as S_Table
FROM            dbo.1102_AC;
```

Comment: I just did. On the actual code I don't have that duplications. Well, maybe I do :( Monday blues... Thanks guys and sorry for taking up your time ...

Answer (score 0):

The union, intersect and except requires the same number of columns (and preferably the ordering too). You have a mistake where you are duplicating the TIMESTAMP on all selects except for the first one.

Comment: Need new glasses I guess... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first line contains 6 columns and rest contains 7 columns because of one extra time stamp column added twice in the rest of the lines.

Union/union all unions the data not that it joins columns. So, you need to mantain same no of columns with type as well to make sure whole data is in sync and consistent